# IOS set element width constraint to 0 when in located inside UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitableview, constraints, autolayout

IOS 6 with auto layout mode.

I have UITableView with Custom UITableViewCell.

It has two UILabels  (Header and Status)

When item status is empty i am need to set Status constraints width to zero, to hide it.
How i can do this?

I am access labels inside UITableViewCell with following technique.

```
UIView *status = (UIView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
status.text=@"Sample text";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to access elements constraints inside UITableViewCell

1-st i am subclass UITableViewCell

Then add IBOutlet

```
@interface UICustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint* statusWidth;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSLayoutConstraint *statusWidth;

@end
```

Then assign it to my cell prototype on the storyboard and link status width constraint with IBOutlet

Now when i dequeue cell

```
UICustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

i am able to set status constraint to zero.

```
cell.statusWidth = 0;
```